# Sitecore Solution Documentation Generation - any tools?

Tags: templates, solution-architecture, documentation

Having had to deliver/create documentation on numerous projects now, I know it is the last thing that anyone wants to do manually in Word.

I happened to see this tool mentioned: https://zkniebel.gitbooks.io/sitecoreuml/

Looks pretty promising for UML diagrams and is bi-directional.

Are there any other tools out there that assist with documenting Sitecore solutions? In particular, documenting the Sitecore Templates, their inheritance, fields, presentation details, etc? Bonus for documenting Sites (and subsites) and IA (Information Architecture), etc. Ideally looking for a complete solution documentation.

If they are bi-directional, like Sitecore UML, even better. As this allows you to not only document, but keep the documentation updated as changes to the templates, etc. occur.

Comment: Honestly, the closest thing you are going to get is Sitecore UML. I don't know of any other documentation available, short of TDS or Unicorn files. Maybe there is an opportunity to add something on to those serialization processes to create additional documentation, but to my knowledge, that doesn't exist out in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is well documented with XML comments, you can use [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).  It's been discontinued by Microsoft, but I have used it in the past.  It will generate MSDN-like documentation in html that is easily navigable.

Comment: Thanks @AaronHawkins - this will definitely help with documenting code, but I am actually seeking other options similar to the SitecoreUML / StarUML functionality. As a minimum, a way to document the Sitecore Templates, their inheritance, etc.